# Why Visual Studio and Dev-C++ does not destroy local variable and other IDEs does: C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14, c++17

I have a very basic question, I don't know it was asked before or not? I have tried to find the answer but could not get it.

I am using **C++** with different IDEs, like **Visual Studio 2019**, **code blocks**, **Dev C++** and online compiler named as **OnlineGDB**.

I have simple code here.

```
#include <iostream>

int* getInt(){
    int x = 10;
    return &x;
}

int main()
{
    int *ptr = getInt();
    std::cout<<*ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

As we know x is a local variable in getInt and when getInt function finish x will be destroyed by the concept of local scope. I am returning reference of x and storing in a pointer which is in main. Now by the book it should not print anything or a garbage value because x is destroyed.

But when I run this code in different IDE they gives different results. Lets see the results.

In **OnlineGDB:**

> warning: address of local variable ‘x’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr].

It shows this warning and does not print any thing.

In **Dev-C++ 5.7.1:**

> warning: address of local variable ‘x’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr].

It shows this warning but also print the value 10.

In **code blocks:**

> warning: address of local variable ‘x’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr].

It shows this warning but does not print any thing.

In **Visual Studio 2019:** It does not show any warning and print the value 10.

So what is actually happening under the hood, what am I missing? Why same code have different results in different environment.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour is Undefined Behaviour. `x` has gone, `ptr` is dangling.  Dereferencing `ptr` is undefined behaviour (no diagnostic required).  Light reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: Turn your warning level up on Visual Studio to Level 4 and then see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @RichardCritten. Ok if it is undefine behavior then why it always prints the value which I set in the x. undefine behavior prints ones, twice but not every time isn't it?

Comment: Don't assume UB is the same as random.. All you can do with Undefined Behaviour is to remove it.  By definition (UB) is impossible  to reason about, there is no cause and effect chain.  It may behave the same for the next 1,000,000 years and then cause Time Travel https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633

Comment: @RichardCritten Got it thanks a lot.

Comment: Another good article on undefined behavior: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, this is just undefined behavior and this can be treated as anything by the compiler when it generates the instructions. In your case, you might be just lucky that the program didn't crash. Take a look at what the same program [here](https://godbolt.org/z/7aqEc5) generates:

```
 mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0xa
 mov    eax,0x0
```

Here `eax` is the register used to store the return value from the function. It populates it with `0x0` and on dereferencing this in the `main()` function, leads to a crash. Check the disassembly of your compilers and see the instructions they generate. Should give you more insight on what might be happening with your compiler. But bottomoline:

> "Don't return address of local variables from function"

Also,

> "Check the warnings from your compiler output."

More likely than not, you would be receiving a warning.

Comment: Try adding `-O3` and see what you get

Comment: @RichardCritten I had seen that since that was the default level for me :). It removes the call altogether to the function and is just a `xor eax, eax` i.e. 0 and in main it just adds in a `ud2` without even calling into `getInt()`. The point I was trying to illustrate is that compilers are free to choose how they go about in UB conditions and just cited an example to illustrate my point.